# juego de golf en c++

Tags: c++

Tengo que entregar un ejercicio en c++ que consiste en un juego de golf, en el cual se pueda jugar con 2 personas y que sea por turnos donde deberán adivinar a cuantas casillas de distancia caerá la pelota en agujero, que el agujero en donde tiene que caer la pelota se genere aleatoriamente y que los jugadores solo tengan 3 oportunidades, si lo hacen a la primera ganan 30 pts, a la segunda 20 pts y a la 3ra 10 y que [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]gane el jugador que realice mas puntos .

La verdad soy principiante en esto y no tengo idea de como hacerlo, si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería.

```
  #include<iostream>
   #include<conio.h>
  #include<windows.h>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include <time.h>

using namespace std;
void inicio();
void players();
void campo();
void personita();
char player1[10],player2[10];
int gol,gol2;




void gotoxy( int x , int y){

    HANDLE manipulador;
    manipulador =GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD Coordenadas;
    Coordenadas.X=x;
    Coordenadas.Y=y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(manipulador,Coordenadas);
    }
    


    void inicio(){
    printf(" Minigolf titulo");

        }
    void players(){


    printf(" Usted es el player \n");
    printf(" Ingrese su nombre \n ");
    scanf("%c",&player1);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf(" Usted es el player 2  \n");
    printf(" Ingrese su nombre  \n " );
    scanf("%c",&player2);
        }
        

        
        void personita(){
    printf("     O   \n");
    printf("    /|\ |  \n");
   printf("     / \ |.  O \n ");


            }
        
    void campo(){

    int i,x,y;

     for(y=0;y<120;y++){
     gotoxy(y,17);
     printf("_");

            }
      srand(time(NULL));
      printf("%d",rand());
      gotoxy(85,19);
      printf("|_|\n");

    introducir el código aquí

 printf(" Dispare por favor un digito \n");
  fflush(stdin);
 scanf("%d",&gol);

 
 
 
    }




    int main()
    {
     inicio();
     gotoxy(79,25);std::cout<<" HECHO POR";
     printf(" Jorge Ramirez Penagos\n");
    
     players();
     personita();
     campo();
     personita();
     getch();
     return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que compartas el código/investigación que llevas cómo avance, de lo contrario podría parecer que lo que quieres es que te resuelvan tu tarea, lo cual no es bien visto en el sitio. Te recomiendo leer el último párrafo de [este link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) de la comunidad.

Comment: cierto tienes razooon

Comment: De paso te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), así podrás obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?